# Configurar el depurador de Visual Studio Code con C/C++

Tags: c++, c, vscode

estoy intentando configurar el depurador para C/C++ con Visual Studio Code. Los programas me compilan y ejecutan correctamente, pero a la hora de pulsar F5 para hacer un paso a paso, me produce el siguiente mensaje de error:

"unable to start debugging unexpected gdb output from command environment cd path
path: No such file or directory"

No sé si tengo algo mal configurado en el launch.json. El contenido de este archivo es:

```
"version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "C/C++: g++.exe Compilar y depurar el archivo activo",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Habilitar la impresión con sangría para gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description": "Establecer tipo de desensamblado en Intel",
                    "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe compilar archivo activo"
        }
    ]
}
```

El compilador que utilizo es migw64. ¿Por qué no puedo depurar?. Gracias de antemano

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta original y no dupliques preguntas. Te sugiero elimines una de las dos preguntas

Comment: Me da la sensación de que la línea `"environment": []` podría estar causando el problema.

Comment: Qué tendría que hacer, ¿eliminarla o añadir algo?

Comment: Prueba a eliminarla.

Comment: Hola, lo he hecho y me da el mismo error. No sé qué hacer. Muchas gracias de todas formas